# Can't disable scrollwheel when adding map using iframe

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I couldn't find email address of support. I have a problem with Google demo-product Fusion Tables. I want to disable the srolling by mousewheel when I add a map using iFrame. But I can't find documentation on setting parameters. I found only the following information about zoom: z=10 (for example) etc.  Can you help me?